# Nested Loop in Edit Form Blade Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have an edit form that used rowspan table and nested loop. I also have a create data form that works fine like this. I used Laravel 8 for this project.

[Create form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWz5r.png)

But when I'm adding the value from database to create the edit form:

[Edit form -1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJrMg.png)
[Edit Form -2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ocIp.png)

I get the sasaran, indikator, and data (questions) from database and then loop it with nested loop. FYI, I have 3 sasaran's data, 12 indikators' data, and 47 questions data that need to load with the rowspan. But when I create the edit form, the rowspan is not fit with the sasaran, indikator, or, question amount, but it loops for 47 times. The rowspan only works for the every first data of sasaran, and then doesn't work for the rest (like the Edit Form -1) and also duplicate the data.

FYI, I didn't used Ajax for create and edit form.

This is the code:

View:

```html
@foreach($sasarans as $i => $sasaran)
@foreach($sasaran->indikator as $indikator)
@foreach($data_laporans as $data)
<tr>
    @if($loop->first)
    <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"
        rowspan="{{$indikator->pertanyaan->count()}}">
        {{$i+1}} </td>
    <td style="vertical-align:middle;"
        rowspan="{{$indikator->pertanyaan->count()}}">
        {{$sasaran->sasaran}} </td>
    <td style="vertical-align:middle;"
        rowspan="{{$indikator->pertanyaan->count()}}">
        {{ $indikator->indikator}} </td>
    @endif
    <td style="vertical-align:middle;">
        <textarea style="height:130px;"
            class="form-control transparent disable"
            readonly>{{ $data->pertanyaan->pertanyaan}}</textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="id_pertanyaan[]" class="form-control"
            value="{{$data->id_pertanyaan}}">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="jumlah[]"
            class="form-control @error('jumlah') is-invalid @enderror"
            value="{{$data->jumlah}}">

        <!--Error Message-->
        @error('jumlah')
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </span>
        @enderror
    </td>
    <td>
        <textarea name="keterangan[]"
            class="form-control @error('keterangan') is-invalid @enderror" value="$data->keterangan"></textarea>

        <!--Error Message-->
        @error('keterangan')
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </span>
        @enderror
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="custom-file"
            style="margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px;">
            <input type="file" name="bukti[]" class="custom-file-input">
            <label class="custom-file-label"></label>
        </div>

        <!--Error Message-->
        @error('bukti')
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </span>
        @enderror

    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

Controller:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $sasarans = Sasaran::all();
    $laporan_indikators = LaporanIndikator::where('id',$id)->first();
    $data_laporans = DataLaporan::where('id_laporan',$id)->get();
    return view('indikator-kinerja.edit',compact('laporan_indikators','data_laporans','sasarans'));
}
```

Sasaran Model:

```
protected $fillable = ['sasaran'];

public function indikator() {
    return $this->hasMany(DataIndikator::class, 'id_sasaran','id');
}
```

Indikator's Model:

```
protected $fillable = ['id_sasaran', 'indikator'];

public function sasaran() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Sasaran::class, 'id_sasaran','id');
}

public function pertanyaan() {
    return $this->hasMany(Pertanyaan::class, 'id_indikator','id');
}
```

Pertanyaan's Model:

```
protected $fillable = ['id_indikator', 'pertanyaan'];

public function indikator() {
    return $this->belongsTo(DataIndikator::class, 'id_indikator','id');
}

public function data_laporan() {
    return $this->belongsTo(DataLaporan::class, 'id_laporan','id');
}
```

Data Laporan's Model:

```
protected $fillable = ['id_laporan', 'id_pertanyaan','jumlah','keterangan','bukti'];

public function laporan() {
    return $this->belongsTo(LaporanIndikator::class, 'id_laporan','id');
}

public function pertanyaan() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Pertanyaan::class, 'id_pertanyaan','id');
}
```

Laporan Indikator's Model:

```
 public function data_laporan() {
    return $this->hasMany(DataLaporan::class);
}
```

I'm really sorry for my bad English, but I'm really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Update: I tried to do this in my view to fix the rowspan, but the question is looping for 47 times for every sasaran and indikator (I mean, not fit with  amount of its sasaran and indikator), and the amount of indikator is not fit with the sasaran. You can take a look to the Create form view that I attached for the example view that I want. I think I know where's the problem is, but I don't really know how to fix it. Please help me because I'm still a beginner. Thank you.

Code for new View:

```
@foreach($sasarans as $i => $sasaran)
 @php ($first = true) @endphp
   @foreach($sasaran->indikator as $indikator)
     @foreach($data_laporans as $data)
       <tr>
       @if($loop->first)
         <td rowspan="{{$data->pertanyaan->count()}}">{{$i+1}} </td>
         <td rowspan="{{$data->pertanyaan->count()}}">{{$sasaran->sasaran}}</td>
         <td rowspan="{{$data->pertanyaan->count()}}">{{$indikator->indikator}} </td>
 @php ($first = false) @endphp
       @endif
       <td style="vertical-align:middle;"><textarea style="height:130px;"
                                                         class="form-control transparent disable" readonly>{{ $data->pertanyaan->pertanyaan}}</textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="id_pertanyaan[]" class="form-control" value="{{$data->pertanyaan->id}}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="jumlah[]" class="form-control @error('jumlah') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{$data->jumlah}}">
          <!--Error Message-->
          @error('jumlah')
           <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
             <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
           @enderror
     </td>
     <td><textarea name="keterangan[]" class="form-control @error('keterangan') is-invalid @enderror">{{$data->keterangan</textarea> 
          <!--Error Message-->
          @error('keterangan')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
              <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
             </span>
            @enderror
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="custom-file" style="margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px;">
        <input type="file" name="bukti[]" class="custom-file-input"> 
        <label class="custom-file-label"></label>
       </div>
     <!--Error Message-->
     @error('bukti')
      <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
       <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
      </span>
     @enderror
   </td>
  </tr>
 @endforeach
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

[New View -1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPi1Y.png) [New View - 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lH2Ik.png)

Comment: Please take the time to format your code for the question. There's no need for 50 leading spaces on lines!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying for some times, finally I found the solution. I just add the variable $data_laporans like this:

```
@foreach($sasarans as $i => $sasaran)
   @php ($first = true) @endphp
   @foreach($sasaran->indikator as $indikator)
     @foreach($indikator->pertanyaan as $pertanyaan)
        <tr>
           @if($loop->first)
              <td rowspan="{{$indikator->pertanyaan->count()}}">{{$i+1}} </td>
              <td rowspan="{{$indikator->pertanyaan->count()}}">{{$sasaran->sasaran}}</td>
               <td rowspan="{{$indikator->pertanyaan->count()}}">{{$indikator->indikator}}</td>
             @php ($first = false) @endphp
             @endif
                <td><textarea>{{ $pertanyaan->pertanyaan}}</textarea></td>
                @foreach($pertanyaan->data_laporan as $data)
                <!--Add your data here-->
                @endforeach
  </tr>
  @endforeach
 @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I also change the relationship between DataLaporan and Pertanyaan:

DataLaporan Model:

```
public function pertanyaan() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Pertanyaan::class, 'id_pertanyaan','id');
}
```

Pertanyaan Model:

```
public function data_laporan() {
    return $this->hasMany(DataLaporan::class, 'id_pertanyaan','id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
What you need to do is only loop a particular amount of indexes in your `data` loop.

```
@php $last_count = 0; @endphp
@foreach($sasarans as $i => $sasaran)
    @foreach($sasaran->indikator as $indikator)
        @foreach(array_slice($data_laporans->toArray(), $last_count, $data_count) as $data)
            @php
                $data_count = $data->pertanyaan->count();
            @endphp
            <tr>
                @if($loop->parent->parent->first)
                    <td rowspan="{{$data_count}}">{{$i+1}} </td>
                    <td rowspan="{{$data_count}}">{{$sasaran->sasaran}}</td>
                    <td rowspan="{{$data_count}}">{{$indikator->indikator}} </td>
                @endif                
                <td style="vertical-align:middle;">
                    <textarea style="height:130px;" class="form-control transparent disable" readonly>{{ $data->pertanyaan->pertanyaan}}</textarea>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id_pertanyaan[]" class="form-control" value="{{$data->pertanyaan->id}}">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="jumlah[]" class="form-control @error('jumlah') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{$data->jumlah}}">
                    <!--Error Message-->
                    @error('jumlah')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @enderror
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     <textarea name="keterangan[]" class="form-control @error('keterangan') is-invalid @enderror">{{$data->keterangan</textarea> 
                     <!--Error Message-->
                     @error('keterangan')
                         <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                             <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                          </span>
                     @enderror
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <div class="custom-file" style="margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px;">
                          <input type="file" name="bukti[]" class="custom-file-input"> 
                          <label class="custom-file-label"></label>
                      </div>
                      <!--Error Message-->
                      @error('bukti')
                          <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                              <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                           </span>
                      @enderror
                  </td>
              </tr>
         @endforeach
         @php $last_count += $data_count; @endphp
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Just try it, and see if it works. I can't debug it myself unfortunately.

**OLD ANSWER:**
The `$loop->first` only works the first time, hence your `sasaran` breaks after first.

Replace the beginning with this:

```
@php
    $tracker = -1;
@endphp
@foreach($sasarans as $i => $sasaran)
    @foreach($sasaran->indikator as $indikator)
        @foreach($data_laporans as $data)
            <tr>
                @php
                    if($tracker !== $i)
                    {
                        $tracker = $i;
                        $new_row = true;
                    } else {
                        $new_row = false;
                    }
                @endphp
                @if($new_row)
                    <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;" rowspan="{{$indikator->pertanyaan->count()}}">{{$i+1}} </td>
                    <td style="vertical-align:middle;" rowspan="{{$indikator->pertanyaan->count()}}">{{$sasaran->sasaran}} </td>
                    <td style="vertical-align:middle;" rowspan="{{$indikator->pertanyaan->count()}}">{{ $indikator->indikator}} </td>
                @endif

                // Your remaining code
```

Try this, and see if it fixes the issue of `sasaran` working only the first time?

Comment: the output is like this: https://imgur.com/a/D83Y4yz. I just add the @else with the first 3 <td> before the endif. Do you have any suggestions to make it without $loop->first?

Comment: I have edited the answer with some mark-up, please check if this is what you did. I'll try to format your code in my local, maybe I can figure it out. Will update the answer if I figure it out.

Comment: I think I have a solution for the issue of the `sasaran` only working the first time, do check.

Comment: I already tried your solution, but the result is still same like the Edit form image that I attach in the question. Here's the link: https://imgur.com/a/nUDFAfp. Can you help me, sir? Thank you

Comment: Yes, what I posted would only help you when the data is initially loaded to display all sets of `sasaran` properly (for your issue: **The rowspan only works for the every first data of sasaran**). Will still not work on edit page. The issue with the edit is that you are adding a new row, but not changing the `rowspan` of the `sasaran` associated with it. You'd have to write some JS or something which will increment the `rowspan` of the `sasaran`, that will probably fix the issue you are facing.

Comment: Ahh okay, I'll try it. Thank you for your suggestion ^^

Comment: Hello, I just update my question about the rowspan. Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: I'll take a look and update if I figure something out!

Comment: Thank you so very much, sir! I'm so sory if I'm disturbing you because I'm still a beginner.

Comment: No no, that's alright. I am still confused as to the structure. You said the questions are looping for 47 times for each `indikator`, as it should because you have a `foreach` within each `indikator`, which is again looped within each `sasaran`. So that will put out a new row for each. I am guessing that is NOT what you want. So what exactly is the layout supposed to be? For each `sasaran`, how many `indikators` should be there? And for each of those, how many `data` should be there?

Comment: Hi sir, sorry for late reply, I attached the full view of edit form and create form here: https://imgur.com/a/b9Bs3n8. I just need the edit form view like the create form with the data (jumlah, keterangan, and bukti; the last three column) value from DataLaporan model to edit, sir

Comment: I checked, and as far as I could see, your `@foreach($data_laporans as $data)` is bringing in 47 rows. And since you're running this loop for each loop of `$sasaran->indikator`, it copies itself everytime. What you want is to separate the loops. I finally understand the issue, I'll try and solve it in the morning. And will update the answer then.

Comment: Okay sir, thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry for being so late, but I think I have finally figured it out. I will update the answer.

Comment: Hi sir, sorry for disturbing you again, there's an error: array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given. The error is appeared after I change the: 
`@php
$data_count = $data->pertanyaan->count();
@endphp`

to:
`@php
$data_count = $indikator->pertanyaan->count();
@endphp`

because it says there's no variable $data

Comment: Oops, my bad. Move the `@php $data_count = $data->pertanyaan->count(); @endphp` after the `@foreach`, and also change the `array_slice()` call, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Hello sir, I'm so sorry for disturbing you again. When I tried the code I got this error: Undefined variable: data_count, so I delete the variable from `@foreach`. But then I got this error: Trying to get property 'pertanyaan' of non-object. Can you help me to solve the problem sir? Thank you

Comment: I added that to reduce calling relations 3 times, but none the less, where ever you see `$data_count`, just replace it with `$data->pertanyaan->count()` again. And remove where I declare the variable.

Comment: Hi sir, I'm so sorry for disturbing you again, but I got an error: Trying to get property 'pertanyaan' of non-object after change `$data_count` to `$data->pertanyaan->count` and remove `$data_count` variable. I wonder if I'm wrong in definition of relationship in my model, but I'm not really sure...

Comment: No your relationship is fine. Since we used `toArray()`, your `->pertanyaan` will now work as `['pertanyaan']`. Just use the `$data` as an array instead of an object inside the loop.

Comment: Hello, I already tried somethin like `$data['pertanyaan']->pertanyaan` and `$data['pertanyaan']['pertanyaan']` but I still got error: Undefined index: pertanyaan. Please help :(

Comment: Just do `{{ dd($data) }}` and see what type of data you get? Comment every other line within, if you need to to check.

Comment: Hello sir, I'm sorry for disturbing you again. After tried for some times, I already solved the rowspan with this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/70655414/17741904. But then I realized that the data is looping to the right and looping the same data on the column at the same time. Can you help me to solved the problem? I also already post a question about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70722369/17741904. Thank you very much for your help, sir.

Comment: I'll take a look, but at this point if the project is not sensitive, maybe you could put it on GitHub or somewhere with a .sql file?

Comment: Hello sir, I'm so sorry for really late reply, because I need to add some things first in the project. You can access it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12DFwVPJz-lcB5aaskIt59dz1-SbUp5nW/view?usp=sharing. I already included the .sql file and the credentials in the project's folder. You can access the view in indikator-kinerja folder. Thank you so very much for your help.