# Duplicate Data When Select With Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to create detail page of [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70451958/nested-loop-in-edit-form-blade-laravel) project. When I tried to get the data, it duplicate for 47 times (I have 47 data for each report) [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DMU5.png). What I need is only one data in a row and then the second data in the next row, etc.. This also happened on the edit page.

My view:

```
@foreach($sasarans as $i => $sasaran)
   @foreach($sasaran->indikator as $indikator)
     @foreach($indikator->pertanyaan as $pertanyaan)
     <tr>
       @if($loop->first)
         <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;" rowspan="{{$indikator->pertanyaan->count()}}">{{$i+1}} </td>
         <td style="vertical-align:middle;" rowspan="{{$indikator->pertanyaan->count()}}">{{$sasaran->sasaran}} </td>
          <td style="vertical-align:middle;" rowspan="{{$indikator->pertanyaan->count()}}">{{ $indikator->indikator}} </td>
       @endif
           <td style="vertical-align:middle;">{{ $pertanyaan->pertanyaan}}</td>
            @foreach($data_laporans as $data)
               <td>{{$data->jumlah}}</td>
               <td>{{$data->keterangan}}</td>
               <td><a href="{{ route('data.download', $data->id) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-block"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Unduh Bukti</a></td>
             @endforeach
        </tr>
     @endforeach
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Controller:

```
 public function show($id)
{
    $sasarans = Sasaran::all();
    $laporan_indikators = LaporanIndikator::where('id',$id)->first();
    $data_laporans = DataLaporan::where('id_laporan',$id)->get();

    return view('indikator-kinerja.show',compact('laporan_indikators','data_laporans','sasarans'));
}
```

I also tried to executed my query in phpMyAdmin and there's no duplicate data. [Data in PhpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNbbv.png)

You can take a look for the model relationship and another details in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70451958/nested-loop-in-edit-form-blade-laravel). I'm so sorry for my bad English. Please help me because I'm still beginner. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying for some times, actually I just need to change the view:

```
 @foreach($sasarans as $i => $sasaran)
   @foreach($sasaran->indikator as $indikator)
     @foreach($indikator->pertanyaan as $pertanyaan)
     <tr>
       @if($loop->first)
         <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;" rowspan="{{$indikator->pertanyaan->count()}}">{{$i+1}} </td>
         <td style="vertical-align:middle;" rowspan="{{$indikator->pertanyaan->count()}}">{{$sasaran->sasaran}} </td>
          <td style="vertical-align:middle;" rowspan="{{$indikator->pertanyaan->count()}}">{{ $indikator->indikator}} </td>
       @endif
           <td style="vertical-align:middle;">{{ $pertanyaan->pertanyaan}}</td>
            @foreach($pertanyaan->data_laporan as $data)
               <td>{{$data->jumlah}}</td>
               <td>{{$data->keterangan}}</td>
               <td><a href="{{ route('data.download', $data->id) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-block"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Unduh Bukti</a></td>
             @endforeach
        </tr>
     @endforeach
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```